# How to add shortcut for Insert Equation in PowerPoint 2016?

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, shortcut

PowerPoint 2016 for Mac finally includes the new-style equation editor (which was already available in Word for Mac and PowerPoint for Windows).  An equation can be inserted using a ribbon button (Insert → Insert Equation).

**How can I add a keyboard shortcut for this?**  Is there already a keyboard shortcut for it?

For Word I could use the OS settings from System Preferences → Keyboard and set up a shortcut for the menu item named "Equation".  But I cannot find a corresponding menu item in PowerPoint.  I can only find this feature on the ribbon, but not the in menu.  Is there any way to set up a keyboard shortcut for it?

Comment: related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1007277/is-there-any-shortcut-to-insert-a-math-equation-for-powerpoint-2016-mac

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [shortcut posted by theoden](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264330/) seems to be broken in new versions.
As a workaround one can just go to the System Preferences => Keyboard => Shortcuts => App Shortcuts and add another one for Microsoft PowerPoint with the "Equation" as Menu Title.

[image]

Comment: what does "add another one for Microsoft PowerPoint with the "Equation" as Menu Title." mean? My keyboard shortcuts look exactly as the ones you have above but it still doesn't work. It only makes a noise when I try to do that short cut in PPT.

Comment: @CharlieParker Is the keyboard shortcut displayed in Powerpoint behind the "Equation" entry in the "Insert" menu?

Comment: @CharlieParker I checked today, and this answer still works for me. I have "Version 16.54 (21101001)", volume licensed, which is not the latest. I have no access to later versions, as I am still on Mojave.

Answer (score 11):

This shortcut is already in PowerPoint:
<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

This produces a place to type an equation when you are in a text box.

Comment: Is there a process to enable it? It doesn't work on my MacBook Air M1 with Office 365 for Mac.

Answer (score 3):

You can't post keyboard shortcuts into comments, so I added an answer. I found out about the German keyboard shortcut (by trial and error). It is:
 <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>´</kbd>

So, on a German keyboard the equals sign has to be replaced with an apostrophe (the key next to the backspace key (on its left)) @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Same as @olik79, I think it is useful to specify that the correct combination on Italian keyboard is <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>ì</kbd>.